# How to make this function slow for certain lines?

Tags: python, performance, printing

Ok, I made a slow printing script, and I am bored so I want to try and make it look cool.
Right now, when I do it, it prints all of the delayed print blocks run all at one speed. What I am trying to do is make some lines run at different speeds. For example "Loading: ||||||||||" would take 5 seconds to write while "Have a great day" takes .05 to write.

Here is my code.
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import time
    import sys

```
def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.01)

delay_print("Hello!")
delay_print("Please wait while this loads :) ")
delay_print(Loading: ||||||||||") #The line that I want to make slower than the rest
delay_print("Thanks!") #return to regular speed.
```

Comment: `'%s' % c` does nothing for strings and should just be `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's what you want:

```
def delay_print(s, t):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(t)

delay_print("Hello!", 0.5)
delay_print("Please wait while this loads :) ", 0.5)
delay_print(Loading: ||||||||||", 5)
delay_print("Thanks!", 0.5)
```